# Finding the max running total in groups of 4

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database that every night gets filled with last days traffic measurements.
We have cars, bicyclist and pedestrian with a sum for each 15 minutes.

I have been looking into running total to find the maximum hour, as in the biggest sum for 4 sequential rows (each row is the sum for the last 15 minutes).

I suppose I need some sort of SUM function with an offset of 4, but have not yet succeeded.

Has anyone of you been up for a similar question, or have any ideas for a smooth running code with the offset?
I am running all the code in Python, importing and exporting to and from the Postgresql database.

Comment: Please add code what you have tried so far with sample data.